# Sails.js + Mongodb Insert a nested json record using ORM

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am using MongoDB in my Sails setup to store my collections.

I am making a POST request through an API, whose request body looks like this :

```
                             **THE REQUEST BODY**
{
    "name":"Martin",
    "phone":"5447874787",
    "comment":"This is a comment",
    "campaign":{
        "campaign_id":123454587,
        "name":"Digital Marketing",
        "category":"Marketing",
        "sub_category":"Digital",
        "product_name":"no product",
        "product_id":5417
    }
}
```

This record is to be stored in my mongodb collection named **"leads"**. My **"Leads"** model looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes:{
        name:{
            required:true,
            type:"string",
            unique: true
        },
        phone:{
            type:"string"
        },
        comment:{
            type:"string"   
        },
        campaign:{
            model: 'lead_campaign_detail',
            // via: "lead_model"
        }
    }
};
```

The associated **"Lead_campaign_detail"** model is as following

```
module.exports = {
    attributes:{
        campaign_id:{
            required:true,
            type:'integer'
        },
        name:{
            type:"string"
        },
        category:{
            type:"string"   
        },
        sub_category:{
            type:"string"   
        },
        product_name:{
            type:"string"   
        },
        product_id:{
            type:"integer"  
        }
    }
};
```

And My controller handler is:

```
create_lead_api:function(req, res){
        Leads.create(params, function(err, resp){
            if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
            else return res.json(resp);
        })

    },
```

> **WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

**1>** I tried using **`.native()`**. It creates a new record BUT it does not care about the attributes in the model "Leads" or the other one. It just saves as the request is.

**2>** Tried creating using the **`.create()`**. It does not stores the nested values of index **"campaign"** in the request: the stored value looks like this:

```
{                     **IN MY DB it looks like**
  "name": "martin",
  "phone": "5447874787",
  "comment": "This is a comment",
  "campaign": "579083f049cb6ad522a6dd3c",
  "id": "579083f049cb6ad522a6dd3d"
}
```

> **I WANT TO**

**1>** Store the record in the same format as the requested am sending.

**2>** Make use of the waterline ORM function **`.create()`** to achieve the same if possible.

**3>** **`.native()`** is also in option if my Model-attributes:{} can be used to bring in between before storing the record. I want to store only values defined in attributes:{ }

Any help is appreciated, Google is failing me.
Thanks

Comment: How do you want your final document in 'leads' collection to look like?

Comment: In the same format the request-body is (nested one):
{
    "name":"Martin",
    "phone":"5447874787",
    "comment":"This is a comment",
    "campaign":{
        "campaign_id":123454587,
        "name":"Digital Marketing",
        "category":"Marketing",
        "sub_category":"Digital",
        "product_name":"no product",
        "product_id":5417
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the document in 'leads' collection to look like your request body, then you should use:

```
campaign: {
    type: "json"
}
```

in your 'Leads' model, rather than linking to 'lead_campaign_detail' collection. You can then do away with the 'lead_campaign_detail' model.

By saying `model: 'lead_campaign_detail'` you are essentially linking the "Leads" document to "lead_campaign_detail", See [Waterline One-way association](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-way-association) and [populate()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values) for more details.

Comment: [upvoted] Hey sorry for late reply and thanks for the answer but, what if i want to add validation to a nested element? Say from the above given example given in the question- I want to add  validation to  "product_name" of  model -"Lead_campaign_detail"?

Comment: And It didn't solves my problem. Document still getting populated without going having entry in my sails- model

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury AFAIK sails doesn't allow validating fields inside subdocuments.
You can use one-way association and populate() (links in answer) to achieve such behaviour, but then your mongo document will not contain the complete Lead_campaign_detail, it will only have the '_id' of the Lead_campaign_detail document.

Comment: I understand. Thanks @rGun